# What is the percentage improvement in time if i use Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

If i am using thread, then by what time the program will  finish execution?

suppose its taking now 35 minutes. If i will thread then by what time the process will finish execution?

How much will be the reduction in time?

Comment: 35 minutes if it is a sequentially blocking task. If not then introduce threads for parallel tasks and calculate the improvement.

Comment: 34%. No. 2%. No 8%. No 17%. How do you expect us to know? What is your code doing? How many threads are you talking about? Do you know for sure the problem can be multithreaded? Without more information this can't be answered.

Comment: Threading by itself does not make something run faster unless it can be parallelized. As it stands, your question is unanswerable because it is heavily dependent on the nature of the operation that is taking 35 minutes.

Comment: @John3136 Suppose i am using 5 threads, then?

Comment: @Darwin you've missed the point - without a LOT more info (e.g. what is your program actually doing?) this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @Darwin Suppose it takes me 15 minutes to drive to the grocery store. If I buy a faster car how long will it take me?

Comment: @immibis nice quote.

Comment: ..or another way, re. 'thread', if it takes 15 minutes to drive to the grocery store in my Ford Focus, how long will it take in an identical Focus from the hire company?

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on the portion that you are parallelizing in it's relation to the entire program, and how well the algorithms within the program lend themselves to parallel computability. There's an old saying `One woman can have a baby in nine months, but nine woman cannot have the same baby in one month`, that is to say "Not all algorithms are efficiently computed in parallel", I/O would be a great example.

Amdahl's Law states that the overall speedup of a program with `n` threads, and a portion `B` of the program is still serial is:

```
                       1
            --------------------------
             B + ( (1 / n) (1 - B) )
```

What this equation tells us is that even the `infinite` speedup of a portion of a program only affects that portion. **For Example:**

Lets say a program has a function `Foo` that lends itself to being run in parallel. After profiling, you find that your program spends 25% of its total runtime in the `Foo` method call. That means that even if you were able to speed up that portion of the program inifinitely, your program would only be 33% (1/0.75) faster.

But, of course, you cannot speedup any portion of your program infinitely with threads, you can just break the work down more. **You have to keep in mind that creating/synchronizing threads has overhead**, so even with 20 threads, you will not gain a 20x speedup.

**But, to answer your original question, lets hypothesize that your entire program can be run in parallel**.

If you were to split the work up **evenly** among `n` threads, I usually find that due to locking, synchronization, and contention, you will usually gain a `0.6 * n` speed increase, in the average case.

Comment: Now for the part where the OP assumes that `0.6 * n` is a universal law, then complains when it isn't accurate.